# Why is gpg --gen-key not asking for key details?

Tags: gnupg

I am using gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.15 on Ububtu 16.04, 64 bit. The `gpg --gen-key` only asks for my name and email ID nothing else. I'd expect it to ask for key size, algorithm, expiration date etc. How can I change the behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use:
`gpg2 --full-gen-key`
and you will be able to set key size, algorithm, expiration date etc.